# How do I read optical transmit power via SNMP on Cisco ASR9k?

Tags: cisco, snmp, cisco-ios-xr, cisco-asr

I am looking to read optical transmit and recieve power of XFPs in our ASR9k. The MIB used should be "CISCO-ENTITY-SENSOR-MIB" which is [1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.91](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.91) and occording the ASR9000 documentation, this is available on ASR9k's:
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/asr9000/mib/guide/asr9kmib3.html#wp2293135
If you scroll up, you will see that the MIB is in the supported list.

So, my question: am I missing something and should this information be available to SNMP, or is the Cisco documentation wrong here?
And if it is available, how can I get to this information?

However show snmp mib object-name | i 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.91 gives me nothing
neither does show snmp mib object-name | i Sensor

> RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:router#show snmp mib object-name | i 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.91
>   Thu May 16 09:08:01.679 CET 
>   RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:router#show snmp mib
>   object-name | i [sS]ensor Thu May 16 09:08:19.017 CET

The version:

> RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:router#show version Thu May 16 09:07:14.437 CET
>
> Cisco IOS XR Software, Version 4.2.3[Default] Copyright (c) 2012 by
>   Cisco Systems, Inc.
>
> ROM: System Bootstrap, Version 1.06(20120210:003513) [ASR9K ROMMON],
>
> cn-asd-kl-cr15 uptime is 23 weeks, 3 days, 1 hour, 12 minutes System
>   image file is
>   "bootflash:disk0/asr9k-os-mbi-4.2.3/0x100000/mbiasr9k-rp.vm"
>
> cisco ASR9K Series (MPC8641D) processor with 4194304K bytes of memory.
>   MPC8641D processor at 1333MHz, Revision 2.2 ASR 9006 AC Chassis with
>   PEM Version 2

And the XFP I am trying to read:

> RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:router#show inventory NAME: "module 0/0/CPU0", DESCR:
>   "8-Port 10GE Low Queue Line Card, Requires XFPs" PID: A9K-8T-L, VID:
>   V04, SN: FOC1641N6EH
>
> NAME: "module mau TenGigE0/0/CPU0/0", DESCR: "Multirate 10GBASE-LR and
>   OC-192/STM-64 SR-1 XFP, SMF" PID: XFP-10GLR-OC192SR  , VID: V04 , SN:
>   SPC1623090S

To compare, this is the output from our 7606:

> 7606#show ver Cisco IOS Software, c7600s72033_rp Software
>   (c7600s72033_rp-ADVIPSERVICESK9-M), Version 15.1(3)S4, RELEASE
>   SOFTWARE (fc2)
>
> 7606#show snmp mib | i Sensor entPhySensorType entPhySensorScale
>   entPhySensorPrecision entPhySensorValue entPhySensorOperStatus
>   entPhySensorUnitsDisplay entPhySensorValueTimeStamp
>   entPhySensorValueUpdateRate entSensorType entSensorScale
>   entSensorPrecision entSensorValue entSensorStatus
>   entSensorValueTimeStamp entSensorValueUpdateRate
>   entSensorMeasuredEntity entSensorThresholdSeverity
>   entSensorThresholdRelation entSensorThresholdValue
>   entSensorThresholdEvaluation entSensorThresholdNotificationEnable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried walking the MIB/OIDs in question from a management station?  After having spent a lot of time w/firmware QA, I've noticed things like show commands are likely to not display correct info, even when the OIDs are poll-able.  I recommend using and knowing Net-SNMP tools and utils as debug before trying to poll the information in cacti, observium, etc.

e.g. `snmpwalk -v2c -c <community> <routername> 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.91` will say "No Such Object available on this agent at this OID" if it's not there

Walking 1.3.6.1.4.1.9 on my IOS-XE box gives a lot (I just need to add the MIBs for description). Then I have something to work with (including other gems that might benefit me for monitoring)

`snmpwalk -v2c -c <community> <routername> 1.3.6.1.4.1.9`

Check out the MIBs available for 4.2.x on the ASR 9000 @:

ftp://ftp.cisco.com/pub/mibs/supportlists/asr9000/asr9000-supportlist.html#Supported_and_Verified_MIBs_XE_4_2_X

That link says that the CISCO-ENTITY-SENSOR-MIB is available, and hasn't been updated since 2007.  Edit: it appears that the ***asr9k-mgbl-p.pie*** package was not available on the router, as mapped in the ASR9000 MIB list above.

**Supplemental info:**

Cisco's MIB Locator tool is IOS-only, so check out the directories above above the asr9000 on the FTP link for more info.

Tool: http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/MIBS/MainServlet

SNMP ftp dir: ftp://ftp.cisco.com/pub/mibs/supportlists/

For more information on loading MIBs: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk362/technologies_tech_note09186a00800b4cee.shtml

A really good Cisco SNMP links page:
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk362/tk605/tsd_technology_support_sub-protocol_home.html

Comment: I seem to be missing the Cisco IOS XR Manageability Package (asr9k-mgbl-p.pie). I will update this in a next service window. Thank you so much.

Comment: **asr9k-mgbl-p.pie** was missing?  Possibly from an upgrade?  Either way, I'm holding on to those SNMP links I just found - handy :)

Comment: I am new at this LIR, so I don't know the reason behind the missing pie. However, on a different ASR, the pie IS installed, and I can indeed get the Tx and Rx power in mW.

Answer (score 5):

The mib 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.91 works on ASR1001s at least.

Running the following from my monitoring box:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c <community-string> <asr1001-name> 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.91
```

Gives an output of:

```
CISCO-ENTITY-SENSOR-MIB::entSensorType.4 = INTEGER: amperes(5)
CISCO-ENTITY-SENSOR-MIB::entSensorType.5 = INTEGER: voltsAC(3)
CISCO-ENTITY-SENSOR-MIB::entSensorType.6 = INTEGER: voltsAC(3)
CISCO-ENTITY-SENSOR-MIB::entSensorType.7 = INTEGER: celsius(8)
CISCO-ENTITY-SENSOR-MIB::entSensorType.8 = INTEGER: celsius(8)
```

And so on.  You'll just have to index it and find the particular sensor you wish to monitor.

(As a note, to get readable output, I had to install the [CISCO-ENTITY-SENSOR-MIB](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.91) on my server that was originating the snmpwalk.)

Answer (score 0):

Below link can be helpful for you :

https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/12577221/snmp-polling-optical-budget-dbm

Comment: Link-only answers are strongly frowned upon. This site is meant to be an archive, and links change or go away over time. You should quote the relevant text from the link, and include the link to properly attribute the quote. It would also be better if you try to explain it.